# can mongodb aggregation skip invalid documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents. It has timestamp field which is mostly Date, and in a few cases it is a string.

If I run aggregation on the timestamp field using time operators (aggregate command) it throws an error:

`can't convert from BSON type String to Date`

Is there a way to skip documents that contain string timestamp and continue with aggregation?

mongodb 3.0.4

Comment: Generally, you should try to keep data types consistent between documents in the collection. I would suggest a long term strategy of correcting the data types (if possible) just for your own sanity.

Comment: you are right, data should be consistent. this measure is just in case (old code used strings - new uses date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$type](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) for matching only documents which have valid date field:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {dateField: {$type: 9} } }
])
```